# MS Access show null values

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I just started learning MS access and I encountered the following problem:

I have a table in Ms Access which I would like to check for fields with no values (Null Values). I have a table with 6 columns for example and I would like to be able to query for all missing data.
The best thing I could come up is a Union Query in which I combined Queries for all columns. The problem I have with this solution is that if there are 2 null values in on row ,I get a duplicate entry in my result.

Is there a better way to show all null values from one table? Or a way to exclude the duplicate from the Union Query?

Thank you!

Comment: 6 columns is not a lot, why not `if col1 is null or col2 is null ...` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. I tried this : Design View->Criteria : Is Null -> The problem is that if I type this at col1 and I type the same thing col2 ,the query is only going to show me data where both col1 and col2 are null.But I want to see also the data where col 1  is null and col 2 is not null and vice versa. So if I type in Design view under all 6 Criteria ,,is null' - the query is only going to show entries where all 6 columns are blank. Or did u meant something ales?

Comment: You must use different lines so you get OR rather than AND, have a look at SQL View in the query design window.

Comment: Yep this worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 columns is not a lot, you can use

```
 if col1 is null or col2 is null ...
```

In the Query Design Window, you must use different lines so you get OR rather than AND, have a look at SQL View to see this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where (Field1 + Field2 + Field3 + Field4 + Field5 + Field6) Is Null
```

This will list all records where one or more fields are Null.

Comment: Thank you but it worked with Fionnuala solution. I guess this works as well , where should I type this command ? should I create a Macro?

Comment: That's the SQL for a query.